# Help verify a proof that a sequence oscillates iff. there exists $a<b$ st.$ x_k≤a$ for infinite times and $x_k≥b$ for infinite times

Tags: real-analysis

The question is

> A sequence $x_1,x_2,x_3…∈\Bbb{R}$  oscillates ($\lim_{k→∞}x_k$  neither converges nor diverges to infinity) iff. there exists $a<b$ st. $x_k≤a$ for infinitely many times and $x_k≥b$ for infinitely many times.

The following is my attempt. It is too long and I have to type it in word.

I feel that my proof is a bit "huge". Can anyone think of a better proof? Thank you!

---

[image]

Comment: Do you treat "diverges to $-\infty$" differently than "diverges to $\infty$"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition $x_k\geqslant b$ i.o. implies that $$\limsup_{n\to\infty} x_n\geqslant b.$$

The condition $x_k\leqslant a$ i.o. implies that $$\liminf_{n\to\infty} x_n\leqslant a.$$

Hence,
$$-\infty \leqslant \liminf_{n\to\infty} x_n \leqslant a < b \leqslant \limsup_{n\to\infty} x_n \leqslant \infty, $$
so that
$$\liminf_{n\to\infty} x_n \ne \limsup_{n\to\infty} x_n $$
and thus $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n$ does not exist.